# Reading from NetworkStream some time get corrupt data

Tags: c#

I have a C++ server that sends orders in the following format:
the first 3 bytes is the message length and the rest of the message is like this:

> enum_code status 0.000000 0.000000 52.260000 52.270000 0.000000
> 0.000000 0 0 0 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1000 0.000000 53.660000 name

I'm reading the buffer like this :

```
private void RecieveMsg(out String message)
{
    message = "";
    byte[] bytes = new byte[3];

    while (!_netStream.DataAvailable)
    {
    }
    //work around for gurbgh data from tcp connection;
    Thread.Sleep(10);

    if (_netStream.DataAvailable)
        _netStream.Read(bytes, 0, 3);

    string returndata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
    //System.Console.WriteLine("RecieveMsg().Header:: " + returndata);
    Int32.TryParse(returndata, out int number);
    byte[] _temp = new byte[number + 1];
    StringBuilder myCompleteMessage = new StringBuilder();
    int totalByetsRead = 0;
    int numBytesRead = _netStream.Read(_temp, 0, number + 1);
    message += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_temp, 0, numBytesRead);
    totalByetsRead += numBytesRead;
    while (totalByetsRead < (number + 1))
    {
        byte[] remaindata = new byte[(number + 1 - numBytesRead)];
        numBytesRead = _netStream.Read(remaindata, 0, remaindata.Length);
        totalByetsRead += numBytesRead;
        message += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(remaindata, 0, numBytesRead);
    }

    message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_temp);
    return;
}
```

If I have more then 10 messages incoming, I'm starting to read some as:

> disable 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 .00??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: Incoming packets can be not in the same order as they was sent. Also you drop out some data with `while` loop. What if there was something useful?

Comment: which `while` loop the first or the second?

Comment: @aepot : You are wrong.  The network adapter reorders packets so application see data in correct order.

Comment: the first one is  busy-wait  until data come from the buffer, the second one is to read the buffer up to the num but byets in the message

Comment: TCP you do not get all the data in one chunk and chunks can be combined and split during routing.  So you need to combine received data with pieces of previous chunks so you do not loose any data.  Ascii encoding will remove non printable character so you probably want to use UTF8 encoding.

Comment: Also if you send that data in a single packet, you may exceed the MTU limit, maximum 1500 bytes per packet but it may be lower regarting to network connection setup. Thus packet can be truncated if you set DNF TCP flag or fragmented by network hosts. Also some packet can be lost and resent later. Btw you may use some ready-to-use protocol e.g. WebSocket instead of implementing your own.

Comment: i tried to cheng the encoding to UTF8 but with the same result, the second `while` loop it to rebuild the line if it came in pieces

Comment: Are you sure your server sends correct data? Have a look with Wireshark.

Comment: @KlausGütter I'm sure - the same code works fine with python client

Comment: Your last statement `message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_temp)` overwrites everything you built up so far with garbage.

Comment: So the message length is sent as three ASCII characters that represent a number? So a length of 5 gets sent as "005" (0x30 0x30 0x35)? Also, why do you allocate a buffer of `number+1`? Also, you return the string from the initial `_temp` buffer, not the `message` string.

Comment: @KlausGütter it solved the problam , writ it as an answer and il accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last statement `message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_temp)` overwrites everything you built up so far in the `message` variable.
If the first read did not contain the complete data, everything after the first `numBytesRead` bytes will essentially contain garbage.

Just remove this line and your code will work.